# Unexpected Redshift support for the ISNULL() function. Is this documented?

Tags: redshift

**As far as I know, the `ISNULL()` function is only compatible with T-SQL.**

Yet, I am working on a Redshift cluster, using Datagrip, that accepts the `ISNULL()` function and returns results without error. I'm even getting the contextual helptext on it in the IDE.

I have found zero Redshift documentation and zero PostgreSQL documentation that even refers to the `ISNULL()` function, let alone confirms support of it. **Is there documentation out there for support of `ISNULL()`? Is this function unofficially supported, since it works, but I can't find any documentation?**

Redshift environment info:

```
DBMS: Redshift (ver. 8.0.2)
Driver: Redshift JDBC Driver (ver. 2.0.0.3, JDBC4.2)
Effective version: Amazon Redshift (ver. 1.0.35480)
```

Comment: I can't see in online documentation. I found on documentation about QuickSight that they have both an `isNUL()` and an `isNotNull()` fucntion: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/isNull-function.html No idea if or how these two products are related (Redshift and Quicksight)

Comment: As pointed out, it is not documented but there might be a chance that it is interpreted as an alias for `COALESCE()`, which is the [documented behaviour](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_NVL_function.html) for `NVL()`. I agree that this should be documented more clearly somewhere, but it might just be that Redshift relies on Quicksight or (less likely) that DataGrip seamlessly converts to the correct alias when querying.

Answer (score 0):

I think redshift recognize ISNULL() to COALESCE() like alias.

Comment: The OP stated that it is seen to work. Do you know of supporting documentation?